# Combined WHERE clause for UNION SELECT in mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I use UNION to get data from two tables, it shows correctly but the issue comes when I have to select different dates intervals to show data between those dates, what happens is that it takes only one where clause and apply that over that single SELECT part rather than over whole query. I need that to be applied over wholle ... how?

```
SELECT
    TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO,
    RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATENEW,
    PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS MONEY,
    CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER,
    PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT
FROM RECEIPTS
    LEFT JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
    LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
    LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE ?(QBF_FILTER)
UNION SELECT
    ADJUSTMENTS.TICKET_NO AS TICKET_NO,
    ADJUSTMENTS.DATE AS DATENEW,
    ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT AS MONEY,
    ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_NAME AS CUSTOMER,
    ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE AS PAYMENT
FROM ADJUSTMENTS
    LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE ?(QBF_FILTER)
```

**>>>>** Above query is taken from UNICENTA open source code project, which uses .bs files for generating reports, when I place WHERE clause over both select parts it generates SQL syntax error, now the issue I discussed above is what I need to resolve, thanks :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a nested Select:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO,
        RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATENEW,
        PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS MONEY,
        CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER,
        PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT
    FROM RECEIPTS
        LEFT JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
        LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
        LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
    WHERE ?(QBF_FILTER)
    UNION SELECT
        ADJUSTMENTS.TICKET_NO AS TICKET_NO,
        ADJUSTMENTS.DATE AS DATENEW,
        ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT AS MONEY,
        ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_NAME AS CUSTOMER,
        ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE AS PAYMENT
    FROM ADJUSTMENTS
        LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
        WHERE ?(QBF_FILTER)
    )
WHERE (yourDate between Date1 and Date2)
```

**EDIT:** I guess it needs to be more like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO_REC,
        RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATENEW_REC,
        PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS MONEY_REC,
        CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER_REC,
        PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT_REC
    FROM RECEIPTS
        LEFT JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
        LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
        LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
    UNION SELECT
        ADJUSTMENTS.TICKET_NO AS TICKET_NO_ADJ,
        ADJUSTMENTS.DATE AS DATENEW_ADJ,
        ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT AS MONEY_ADJ,
        ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_NAME AS CUSTOMER_ADJ,
        ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE AS PAYMENT_ADJ
    FROM ADJUSTMENTS
        LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
    )
WHERE ?(QBF_FILTER)
```

Comment: This nested select statement still generates the same SQL syntax error, that's what I want to prevent !

Comment: Weird, I don't know what is passed in your WHERE clauses in the sub-selects. Can you take those 2 out and see what it gives you?

Comment: it takes date that is DATENEW in both selects, if I take out both WHERE clauses it gives SQL syntax error near UNION SELECT .. :(

Comment: I presume ?(QBF_FILTER) is a place holder for a parameter, hence needing the number of place holders to match the number of parameters. If so I would expect the 2nd query to work.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Try again the second example. Notice that I've changed the resulting variable names in each Select statement. You will need to modify your parameter QBF_FILTER accordingly.

Comment: Finally it worked, I have to change the placements of parameters in both selects as QBF_FILTER takes dates format so that I have to put DATENEW in the top in both of SELECT statements as when they return result DATE should be on top to compare with the result of QBF_FILTER, thanks anyways you helped a lot :)